# python Paho client MQTT : writing to multiple files

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

Initialize a MQTT client, connect to the MQTT broker on a specific topic, for each message received on that topic execute a function call to check if the length of an attribute in message is greater than 200, if yes then find the Gyro meter reading: GyroX & save to file ensuring that the file size is kept less than say 400MB if not then open a new file and start writing to it.

Referring post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54306598/12097046

I want to write to multiple files i.e. post incoming json messages to different files based on size instead of just one file. how to do it ? any help is appreciated

```
file_name='/tmp/gyro_256'+"_"+timestr+".csv"
def on_message(client, userdata, message):
  y = json.loads(message.payload)
  v = (len(y['sec_data']))
  p = int(v)
  if p >= 200:
          d = (y["sec_data"][10]["GyroX"])
           with open(file_name,'a+') as f:
                    f.write(d + "\n")
client = mqttClient.Client("123")               #create new instance
client.username_pw_set(user, password=password)    #set username and 
client.on_connect= on_connect                      #attach function to 
  
client.on_message= on_message                      #attach function to 
   
client.connect(broker_address,port,100) #connect
client.subscribe("tes1") #subscribe
client.loop_start() #then keep listening forever
if int(os.path.getsize(file_name)) > 47216840 :
     client.loop_stop()
     timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
     file_name = '/vol/vol_HDB/data/gyro_256'+"_"+timestr+".csv"
client.loop_start()
```

Comment: You've not explained what is not working with the code you've posted.

Comment: You also need to fix the indentation of that code.

Comment: @hardillb sorry about the indentation.. will try to correct...

Comment: @hardillb  I want to know if its possible to switch the file name like below by breaking the loop, above code does not work...



client.loop_start() #then keep listening forever
  if int(os.path.getsize(file_name)) > 47216840 :
     client.loop_stop()
     timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
     file_name = '/vol/vol_HDB/data/gyro_256'+"_"+timestr+".csv"
  client.loop_start()

Comment: Edit the question to add detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the code after the fist call to `client.loop_start()` will ever be run because that call blocks forever.

If you want to change the file name you will have to do the file size test in the `on_message` callback.

```
def on_message(client, userdata, message):
  global filename
  y = json.loads(message.payload)
  v = (len(y['sec_data']))
  p = int(v)

  if int(os.path.getsize(file_name)) > 47216840 :
     timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
     file_name = '/vol/vol_HDB/data/gyro_256'+"_"+timestr+".csv"

  if p >= 200:
    d = (y["sec_data"][10]["GyroX"])
    with open(file_name,'a+') as f:
      f.write(d + "\n")
```